# Checking of python fails as: testing of pyembed fails

Tags: python-2.7

When I try to do a waf configuration, I get the following error:

> Asking python-config for pyembed '--cflags --libs --ldflags' flags :
>   yes  Testing pyembed configuration:Could not build a python embedded
>   interpreter

The error is difficult to understand and solve. Can anyone please help me to fix this error?

Comment: you should post the config you have created

Comment: Please use the link below to find the attached config.log file. Thank you. The software to build is Code_Aster. http://www.filedropper.com/configlog